# Passing Instance variable in a hidden form variable in ERB view with Sinatra not working

Tags: ruby, variables, sinatra, instance, erb

Let me preface by saying I am sure I am doing a lot wrong here. I am trying to write a silly mad libs type program where a user can alter the recipe. First I have the following method to create the mad lib.

```
def madlib_recipe
    recipe = "recipe text"

    #tag words  
    tagger = EngTagger.new
    recipe = tagger.add_tags(recipe, true)

    #create for textboxes
    recipe = recipe.split(".")
    i=0
    recipe.map! do |sentence|
        size = sentence.size
        sentence = sentence.split(" ").map! do |word| 
                               i+=1
                                          word.size.odd? && word.size<40  && word.include?        ('punctuation') == false && word.include?('determiner') == false ?
                          word = "<input type='text' size='#{word[/<.+?>/].size}'' name='text#{i}' style='border:1px dotted gray;' placeholder='#{word[/<.+?>/]}'>" : word
                          end

        sentence = sentence.join(" ")
    end
    recipe.join(".")
end
```

Then I have the following route with an erb view:

```
get '/nine' do
    @name = 'DIY'
    @content = madlib_recipe

    erb :dyi
end
```

in the `:dyi` view I have with the following hidden input:

```
<div text-align:justify;><%=@content%></div>
<input type ='hidden' name='recipe' value= <%=@content"%>>
```

Everything works fine except for the fact that the hidden input shows the contents of the `@content` instance variable, and when I parse the parameters on the post route the `@contents` value does not show.  Being a neophyte I am sure I am make all sorts of terrible decisions here and I look forward to being corrected.

Comment: Is `madlib_recipe` inside a [helpers](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers) block?

Comment: What’s with all the `#` characters around your `<`s and `>`s? Did you add them just to get them to show up in the question?

Comment: Yes added # character so <> would show up. And iain yes, mad lib_recipe is in a helpers block.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem happens later, when you submit a form on the generated HTML page to another route (post '/something' do...). In which case you should start by showing the generated HTML, at least the part with the form.

Comment: I fixed the problem by using <input type ="hidden" name="recipe" value=<%="\"#{@recipe}\""%>>